# Image is not shown with this code in storage and gallery

Tags: android, image

I am saving the image using this code. Image is saved in devices having sdcard slot. But The devices which have only internal memory or device Storage like Samsung SM-J710F are not saving the image.

My code:

```
private void saveImageAsJpeg() {
    Bitmap bitmap = _paintView.getDrawingCache();
    Date d = new Date();
    CharSequence s = DateFormat.format("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss", d.getTime()); // MM-dd-yy hh-mm-ss
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/dcim/MyImageFolder/"+ s + ".jpg");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Image Saved at " + file.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    try {
    if (!file.exists()) {
            //file.createNewFile();
            file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
         }
        FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream);
        ostream.close();
        if (file.toURI() != null)
          {
            new MediaScannerNotifier(FillColorActivity.this, file.toString(), MIME_PNG);
          }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
```

I have gone through multiple solutions on stack but didn't get the proper solution.

Comment: what is paintView? ImageView?

Comment: @Abhishek it is an object of View Class from where I am getting my bitmap

Comment: You are creating a directory if a file does not exists. That looks nonsense. Moreover you are not checking the return value of mkdirs().

Comment: being a newbee to android I dont know exactly how to do that. Please guide  me for that

Comment: Where is the try-catch for the FileOutputStream?

Comment: You should only create a directory if that directory does not exists of course. Start with checking and creating the directory. After that you can do someting with files that should go in.

Comment: @N.R I tried your code. It is not able to create /dcim/MyImageFolder/ structure. So how I you store it? You have go with another approch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save the view as image in SDcard you can try the following methods,

```
public static void saveMyView(View view, Context context) {
    Date d = new Date();
    CharSequence fileName = DateFormat.format("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss", d.getTime()); // MM-dd-yy hh-mm-ss

    final File file;

    if(isExternalStorageReadable()) {
        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), "MyImageFolder/");
    } else {
        file  = new File(context.getFilesDir().getPath(), "MyImageFolder/");
    }

    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdir();
    }

    saveBitmapInFile(new File(file.getAbsoluteFile(), fileName + ".jpg"), getBitmapFromView(view), context);
}

public static boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private static void saveBitmapInFile(File file, Bitmap bitmap, Context context) {
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(file);

        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);

        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        context.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {

    view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

    view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());

    view.buildDrawingCache();

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

    Drawable drawable = view.getBackground();
    if (drawable != null)
        drawable.draw(canvas);

    view.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but my code is working fine for sd card storage.. but not for device(phone/internal) storage. I want to save in device if there is no sd card mounted in device

Comment: thanks for the solution. I tried it but its still not working in the device where there is no sd card.

Comment: In the above code, If the sdcard is not mounted it will store in internal memory(context.getFilesDir()).

Comment: but the device where no sd card is yet mounted is not storing the image

Comment: Yes thats wat I am telling we can see in any folder if we use context.getFilesDir()

Comment: You can check but writing code to get the file and dispaly

Comment: It will store inside /data/data/[your pacakge]/[files] you cant see in normal fileexplorer

Comment: I didn't get that. Can u please explain

Comment: No its not.. I checked file explorer there is no folder or image created anywhere

Comment: If we store in context.getFilesDir() means it will be space for our application other application cant access this files, it will locate in /data/data/[your pacakge]/[files], This files have access right to your app only.

Comment: Then how do I display them in gallery.

Comment: thats what I am telling you can't see in file explorer

Comment: but the aim of mine to save image is to display it in gallery. Is there any solution to access it in gallery or let me know the alternate solution for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151867/discussion-between-muthukrishnan-rajendran-and-n-r).

Answer (score 0):

try this example hopes this will help you. call selectpic() on your button click.

```
public void selectpic() {
    final Dialog myDialog = new Dialog(this);
    myDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    myDialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
    myDialog.setTitle("Choose Picture");
    Button btncamera = (Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.btncamera);
    Button btngallery = (Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.btngallery);

    //EnableRuntimePermission();

    //Select Camera
    btncamera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ClickImageFromCamera() ;
            myDialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    //Select image from gallery
    btngallery.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            GetImageFromGallery();
            myDialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    myDialog.show();
}

public void ClickImageFromCamera() {
    CamIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File sdCardDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            "MyFolder/Media/Profile");
    sdCardDirectory.mkdirs();

    File image = new File(sdCardDirectory, "tempProfilepic" + ".jpg");
    uri = Uri.fromFile(image);
    CamIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
    CamIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    startActivityForResult(CamIntent, AppConstants.REQUEST_CAMERA);
}

public void GetImageFromGallery(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    //intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    try {
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                "Complete action using"), AppConstants.SELECT_FILE);

    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        if (requestCode == AppConstants.REQUEST_CAMERA) {
            ImageCropFunction();
        }
        else if (requestCode == AppConstants.SELECT_FILE) {
            if (data != null) {
                String path = data.getDataString();
                uri = Uri.parse(path);
                Bitmap photo = null;
                try {
                    photo = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),uri);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //External sdcard location
                File sdCardDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        "MyFolder/Media/Profile");
                sdCardDirectory.mkdirs();
                File finalimage = new File(sdCardDirectory, "tempProfilepic"+ ".jpg");

                boolean success = false;
                FileOutputStream outStream;
                try {
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(finalimage);
                    photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
                    outStream.flush();
                    outStream.close();
                    success = true;
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (success) {
                    uri = Uri.fromFile(finalimage);
                    ImageCropFunction();
                }
            }

        }else if (requestCode == AppConstants.CROP_FILE) {
            if (data != null) {
                fileselected = true;
                String path = data.getDataString();
                if (path != null){
                    uri = Uri.parse(path);
                }else{
                    uri = uri;
                    //Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                    //Bitmap selectedBitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");
                }

                Bitmap bitmap = null;
                try {
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),uri);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                btnprofilepic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                File sdCardDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        "MyFolder/Media/Profile");
                sdCardDirectory.mkdirs();

                File finalimage = new File(sdCardDirectory, "Profilepic"+currentDateandTime+ ".jpg");

                File tempimage = new File(sdCardDirectory, "tempProfilepic" + ".jpg");
                if (tempimage.exists()) {
                    tempimage.delete();
                }
                boolean success = false;
                FileOutputStream outStream;
                try {
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(finalimage);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
                    outStream.flush();
                    outStream.close();
                    success = true;
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (success) {
                    selectedfile = finalimage.toString();

                } else {
                    //app.showToast("Error during image saving");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public void ImageCropFunction() {
    try {
        CropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        CropIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
        CropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        CropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 500);
        CropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 500);
        CropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        CropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        CropIntent.putExtra("scale", true);
        startActivityForResult(CropIntent, AppConstants.CROP_FILE);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

    }
}//Image Crop Code End Here
```

*********************Custom dialog XML File******************

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/White"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="25dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtheader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="Select an Image to upload"
    android:textColor="@color/Black"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="normal" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/White" />


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btncamera"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Take Photo"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btngallery"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="From Gallery"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="14dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                "Complete action using"), AppConstants.SELECT_FILE); what is AppConstants in this line

Comment: AppConstant is a java class file where i declare SELECT_FILE with value 101.